# How to install a forked gem on Engine Yard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use the LinkedIn gem But not the one that I get when I type

```
sudo gem install linkedin
```

I want a specific one that somehow has done patches to. It is a fork of the original which is:

http://github.com/jbasdf/linkedin

I have downloaded sources from the above link, and use "rake" command to build a gem locally. So everything is working fine locally.

But now I have a question. How can I setup this folked gem on the server (engine yard)? I am not sure how to bild a gem on the server in this case.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pre-built gem is available on a server(gem cutter) you should be able to use Trip's method.

If not two options spring to my mind:

1) Write a chef script that clones the source from github and builds it.

2) Use bundler with its built in support for building gems from a git url. EY fully supports bundler.

I think the latter would be a better choice, as it completely removes the need to use EY's UI for managing gems and is a step towards Rails 3 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can log into EY's cpanel. On your dashboard, Click "Application" in your instance, and then click on the Ruby Gem Icon. In this panel you can download gems to install on your server including what version you want them as well.